# How to show basic HTML Windows8 Metro style TextBlock?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have an html page that only contains `<p>`, `<strong>`, `<br />` and `<a>` tags. I want to show this content in a XAML `TextBlock` in Windows 8. Is there any way to show that content in a `TextBlock` without losing the structure (e.g. paragraphs)? I don't want to use `WebView` because `WebView` can not be transparent.

Comment: Can you use a [RichTextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblock)?  You'd have to translate the HTML markup into paragraphs, etc. yourself.  Except Metro doesn't support inline hyperlinks, though there is a [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9882353/292432).

Comment: Yes, I can use a RichTextBlock. However, I do not know how to populate a RichTextBlock dynamically. I was using Binding.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762150/coloring-text-in-richtextbox-c-sharp/3762469#3762469) creates rich content dynamically.  It's actually for Silverlight, but I'd be surprised if the code was much different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am developing a open source Windows 8 Metro RSS Reader app and I used [HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.html.htmlutilities.converttotext)

You can see the source code implementation here http://metrorssreader.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/17913#265003

Comment: sweet zombie jesus thank you for linking to this. I had no idea this was baked into the frame work and lost a ton of time chasing my tail and getting nowhere! thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it in XAMl, just add a converter.

```
    public sealed class TextToHtmlConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            return HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText(value.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML add a resource reference.

Then Bind with a converter:

Text="{Binding titleFull,Converter={StaticResource TextToHtmlConverter}}"