# Convert simple HTML to a RichTextBlock

Tags: html, wpf, xaml, windows-8, richtextblock

I am starting with Windows 8 and I am trying to convert HTML to a `RichTextBlock`.

I [have read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491134/how-to-show-basic-html-windows8-metro-style-textblock) that I could use this function :  `HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText` in a `TextBlock` but I can't find a way to use this function in a `RichTextBlock`!

From what I understand and tried [I can't extend](http://geoffwebbercross.blogspot.pt/2011/09/richtextblock-xaml-bindable-rich-text.html) the `RichTextBlock` so I can't apply this function everytime a `RichTextBlock` is called.

Also, I can't find any way to bind text to a `RichTextBlock` and [building a parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088034/showing-html-in-winrt-with-richtextblock-or-other-component) just for simple HTML (I only want paragraphs and italics/bolds) seems an overkill. Also, I have no idea where I should do this parsing since I the `RichTextBlock` seems unextendable.

I can't use the `WebView` because I **need** transparency (and from what I have read the [WebView doesn't have it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-BE/winappswithcsharp/thread/c47c0f2e-b2c7-4691-8a20-929174504877)).

**EDIT**

@mydogisbox made me see I was getting too far on my research.

I can use `HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText` in the getter of a property that I can bind in the `RichTextBlock`. I couldn't bind it because I was trying to do 
                    `<Run Text="{Binding TextHTML}" />` without a `<Paragraph>` tag.

However `HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText` doesn't preserve italics or bolds. Only paragraphs :/.

Comment: You should be able to just call the ConvertToText function in the property you have bound to your RichTextBlock.  What problems did you have doing it that way?

Comment: God. I was totally lost on my research. I had a problem with `<Run Text>`. Now I have realized that I need a `<Paragraph>` before so I could use it. I have binded it and tried to use a converter before I saw your comment. The converter was crashing but after I saw your comment I have changed my property's getter and now is working! However, I found out that `HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText` doesn't convert italics/bolds. I only need italics, bolds and paragraphs :/. Going to update the question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If you just need those three, then maybe you could make a simple parser that converts those three things into text in the html and then you could parse again after running it through `ConvertToText` to parse those into italics etc.

Comment: Supose I do that parsing (I am going to save that solution for last). How can I add the "generated" tree to the xaml? Can I still bind and separate the parsing from the Model? Kinda lost since I got into windows 8 today :p

Comment: I think so.  You would just have a method that converts the html to your type of html and then another method which converts the result of the `ConvertToText` to something the RichTextBox can display.  Should just be chained method calls in the property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using a [package avaiable on gitHub](https://github.com/MacawNL/WinRT-RichTextBlock.Html2Xaml) that converts from HTML to a RickTextBlock.

Basiclly you only need to open the Package Manager Console (Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console) and [install the package](http://nuget.org/packages/RichTextBlock.Html2Xaml) running `Install-Package RichTextBlock.Html2Xaml`.

Then you open RichTextBlockProperties.cs and you have the lines you need to copy. In my case I had to add the namespace:

```
xmlns:rtbx="using:EventTests.Common"
```

And then you can bind your property that has HTML using:

```
<RichTextBlock rtbx:Properties.Html="{Binding ...}"/>
```

**Some problems and some solutions**

A problem I have found with this library is how it handles simple html with no divs. Like:

```
<p>Testing <i>italic</i> and something more.</p>
<p>More testing </p>
```

This prints:

> Testing *italic* and something more.
>
> More testing

However, I wanted something like this:

> Testing *italic* and something more.
>
> More testing

So I had to wrap the second paragraph in a div (and all paragraphs except the first could be wrapped).

```
<p>Testing <i>italic</i> and something more.</p>
<div><p>More testing </p></div>
```

If you wrap the first paragraph then you will have an extra new line.

So far this is the best solution I have found. If you find better I apreciate it since I am testing and learning. If you find a better solution I will accept yours.

**Be carefull**

This approach will crash if you have symbols like "<" or "&" in your html. I suggest that you replace those chars before you try to use this library.

Comment: I ended up editing the accompanying xslt to add Margin="0,10,0,0" to the <Paragraph> tag instead. Same result, more or less. Note that I didn't mind the first paragraph having the margin as well due to how my containers were already lined up...

Comment: Question regarding Be careful section of your answer. I am getting exception and offcourse in my html there are tags which contains '<'.
how can I get rid of it? And I can't change my html because service is not in my hand.

Comment: and I'm getting html through service. Could I encode that string or something like that???

Comment: I encoded through this System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(obj.DescriptionEN);
now its not giving error exception but printing whole html there with tags :(